# How do I fix my module so an external library has no problem running require_once?

Tags: uri, theming

I'm writing a wrapper module for an external library. Now when I create a new instance of a class defined in the external library I get an error message:

```
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '../../directory1inlibrary/fileinlibrary.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')
```

The file which defines the class is in `libraries/libraryname/directory2inlibrary/subdirectoryinlibrary`, so a priori it looks fine. However, apparently once I use the file from within Drupal the path of the file is ignored. How do I fix this without doing anything to the library? Should I simply define a global path in my module to include all the library directories?

Comment: I guess you'll need to interject some code before that require is executed that changes the current working directory to the correct one. You won't want to hear it, but the proper way to solve it would be to fix the bug/shortcoming (depending on your point of view) in the external library

Comment: Okay, I'll try and do that. I'm surprised by your answer though, because the relative path used is correct.

Comment: To get a better idea of what's going on, insert `die(getcwd())` just before the line it dies on - that'll tell you what the current working directory is, and might help to determine exactly what's going wrong

Comment: Is the library in your drupal directory?